# I want to loop through array and dynamically output result.. if there is no match I would like to output another result

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects and when the user inputs a zipcode and click I want to loop through the array and if the users zipcode matches a zip code in the array output results if the zipcode dose not match output another result

I have attempted to use map and forEach on the array and each allow me to find the zipcode and provide out put Im running into trouble when the zipcodes do not match

```
class PricingTool extends Component {
  state = {
    zipCode: "",
    finalZip: "",
    routine: "",
    rush: "",
    sameDay: "",
    city: "",
    match: false
  };

  handleKeypress = e => {
    const { zipCode } = this.state;
    if (e.which === 13 && zipCode.length === 5) {
      console.log("enterrerre");
      this.zipcodeHandler();
    }
  };

  zipcodeHandler = () => {
    const { zipCode } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      finalZip: zipCode,

    });
  };

  changeHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.target.value.length <= 5 && !isNaN(e.target.value)) {
      this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { finalZip, zipCode, match } = this.state;
    let searchResult;

    if(finalZip){
      searchResult = zipCodes.map(cur => {
      if (finalZip && finalZip == cur.zip) {        
        return (
          <div className="pricing__searchResult">
            <h1 className="pricing__searchResult-1">
              We do serve in {cur.city}, Indiana
            </h1>
            <div className="pricing__searchResult-2">Same-Day</div>
            <div className="pricing__searchResult-3">{cur.fees.sameDay}</div>
            <div className="pricing__searchResult-4">Rush</div>
            <div className="pricing__searchResult-5">{cur.fees.rush}</div>
            <div className="pricing__searchResult-6">Routine</div>
            <div className="pricing__searchResult-7">{cur.fees.routine}</div>
            <div className="pricing__searchResult-8">
              Please call us or email info@ccprocess.com to order
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
    }
```

I would like it to find the user inputed zip code if it is in the data array and if it is not then render another message

Comment: Without looking to closely at the code, it looks like all you need to do is add something like `else return <div>No match</div>;` so your render() function will always return something.

Comment: Where do you actually input the zipcode? like from where does the handlekeypress() is invoked?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a Array `map` method, which would map each value of the array to something else (in your case, it would only map the zipcode found), you can (and should) use a better method for the job. The `find` method will find the first item that meet your criteria and return it, in your case, it could be `finalZip && (finalZip == cur.zip)`. If no item is found for the expression given, `undefined` is returned.

```
render() {
    const { finalZip, zipCode, match } = this.state;
    let searchResult;

    if(finalZip){
      searchResult = zipCodes.find(cur => finalZip && (finalZip == cur.zip));
      if(searchResult) {
          // do something for when the zip code is found
      }
      else {
          // do something when no zip code is found
      }
    }
}
```

Array `find` method documentation: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: `.find` is not supported in IE, `.filter` may be your best bet.

Comment: IE support is not mentioned on the question so I didn't considered it, however, he can use a polyfill to had support for it if he ever needs it.

Comment: It wasn't mentioned but it is something to consider when developing web applications.

Comment: I agree with @DavidFontes - a great deal of people have switched off of IE if you look at the Browser market. It's no longer a staple ( ~5% ) and unless specifically requested it isn't really necessary to go out of your way to provide support for.

Comment: @zfrisch I would very much disagree, I work in a company which uses IE for specific software and many people use the browser. Just because you have one statistic which says it isn't used as much doesn't mean you should ignore coding for those cases.

Comment: @RyanWilson ...and just because you have to support IE doesn't mean we should ignore several versions' worth of ECMAScript advancements.

Comment: @RyanWilson right, but just because your company uses it for specific software doesn't mean everyone needs to be given the task( and headache ) of pointing out where it wouldn't be viable because IE's implementations are so far behind atm. There's nothing wrong with pointing it out, but it's understandable that it's not a large priority of the community to break their backs rewriting things to be IE compliant.

Comment: @zfrisch (https://hostingfacts.com/internet-facts-stats/) shows that 3.8 billion people use the internet. Even at 5%, that is still 190 million people which you are alienating by not coding something to work with Internet Explorer.

Comment: @RyanWilson I'm not saying you're wrong, I was just pointing out that it's understandable why it wouldn't be of the highest concern if the OP didn't specifically say so. I meant no offense, and I suppose we'll just have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @zfrisch I can see why you wouldn't consider it, but in my opinion it is a bad business practice to not account for such a large number of potential business clients ie. the 190 million internet users out there. I suppose it would depend on what the OP's purpose is for their web application. I personally do not like having to account for IE and can't wait for the day it is phased out completely.

Comment: @RyanWilson haha, agreed. I thank God every day that Microsoft is throwing in the towel and moving to Chromium.

Comment: @zfrisch Same here. Have a good day. Sorry if I came off as defensive. I just have learned through my own personal experience that not accounting for IE can cause for a lot of headache in development. Anymore, I debug everything in IE and if it works I can pretty much assume it will work in the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Being not sure what all components you used or are currently in your application, I created a sample app which kind of simulates your requirement and possibly delivers the correct output.

So here, I had no idea of where the input will be taken from the user and how your onKeyPress listener would work, so I created another component that renders your data based on the input and check if that zipcode exist or not.

Like shown below, your ZipCode related information will be render by another component `ZipTool` and your input box is handled by `PricingTool`

Also, here's the jsfiddle if you want to play around with the code - https://jsfiddle.net/hf9Ly6o7/3/

I hope you find this useful.

```js
class ZipTool extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
  }
 render() {
   let { data } = this.props;
   return (
     <div>
        <h1 className="pricing__searchResult-1">We do serve in { data.city }, Indiana</h1>
        <div className="pricing__searchResult-2">Same-Day</div>
        <div className="pricing__searchResult-3">{ data.fees.sameDay }</div>
        <div className="pricing__searchResult-4">Rush</div>
        <div className="pricing__searchResult-5">{ data.fees.rush }</div>
        <div className="pricing__searchResult-6">Routine</div>
        <div className="pricing__searchResult-7">{ data.fees.routine }</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class PricingTool  extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     zipCodes: [
            {
                   'zipcode': '12345', 
                    'city': 'abc', 
                    'fees': {
                     'sameDay': '43', 
                      'rush': '90', 
                      'routine': '20'
                    }
                  },
                  {
                   'zipcode': '54321', 
                    'city': 'xyz', 
                    'fees': {
                     'sameDay': '25', 
                      'rush': '35', 
                      'routine': '10'
                    }
                  }
           ],
     zipCode: "",
      finalZip: "",
      routine: "",
      rush: "",
      sameDay: "",
      city: "",
      match: false
    }
    
  }
 
  
  changeHandler(e) {

     this.setState({
        zipCode: e.target.value,
      });
      
      for (let code of this.state.zipCodes) {
        if( code.zipcode === e.target.value ){
          this.setState({match: true, finalZip: code})
          break;
        }
        else {
          this.setState({match: false, finalZip: null})
        }
      }
    
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.changeHandler.bind(this)} onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} name={this.state.zipCode}></input>
        <div className="pricing__searchResult">
          { this.state.finalZip ? <ZipTool data={this.state.finalZip} /> : <div>Not Found</div> }
          <div className="pricing__searchResult-8">
            Please call us or email info@ccprocess.com to order
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PricingTool  />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.done {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```